# How to bundle python modules into single [executable] zip archive?

Tags: python, package, bundle

Its been quite a while since I wrote any serious python code so I'm sure I'm just missing something stupid...

I've written several modules and would like to bundle them into a single executable zip archive. I seem to remember this being a relatively trivial process and thought I had it working but after a few additions, renaming directories/files, etc. I'm unable to make heads or tails of the steady tide of errors.

While researching the question, I came across a number of hits for packaging with the preverbal Cheeseshop (`pip`), `py2exe`, `py2app`, etc. However, I have no intention of redistributing my code online and don't necessarily need to bundle the entire python environment.

What is the easiest and simplest method for bundling my modules into a single cross platform (mostly unix/linux/mac environment) executable?

Example Structure:

```
ProjectRoot
    |_ sub_dir
        |_ __init__.py # empty file
        |_ module1.py
        |_ module2.py
    |_ __main__.py
```

Contents of `__main__.py` :

```
import sub_dir.module1 as sss
sss.main()
```

I attempted to create a zip archive of the `ProjectRoot` but when executing the archive I get the following:

```
$ python ./ProjectRoot.zip
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: can't find '__main__' module in './ProjectRoot.zip'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `zipapp` module:

```
$ python -m zipapp myapp -m "myapp:main"
$ python myapp.pyz
```

↳ https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html